# REact/redux app api call not working : showing empty and aciton not running issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, redux

hi guys I am creating a react native app having some problem when calling api get request
its like the response giving some error seems like action not running  ill share  code below please if anyone  know the issue please  let me know

> NOTE -- when I run the app console in reducer and console in action
> are not running aslo

---

error message in console DetailsReducer reducer value in component  when i do mapstatetoprops and check the value of reducer its showing like below

```
Object { details: {}, isFetching: false, error: false }
details: Object {  }
<prototype>: Object { … }
error: false
isFetching: false
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

---

action file

```
export function fetchdetails(seesionkey) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    fetch(`api url`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          seesionkey,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "appcont": getState().mustdata,
          "dataset":{}
        }),
      })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then((rr) => {
        console.log('------testinresponse',rr);
        if (rr.response.error.errorCode === -4) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCHFAIL',
            payload: ' error  again',
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCHSUCCESS',
            payload: rr,
          });
        }

  })
}
}
```

---

reducer

```
const initialState = {
    details: {},
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}
export default function DetailsReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case :FETCHSUCCESS
            console.log('action goes here', action)
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                details: action.payload
            }
        case FETCHFAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

component call

---

```
componentDidMount() {
 const {seesionkey} = this.props
 this.props.dispatch(fetchdetails(seesionkey));

  }
```

---

mock api

```
{   
    "appcont":{
      "id":"34435654605",
      "name":"no data ",
      "details":dummy details",
      "code":"demo",
      
   },
   "dataset":{
        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution data was empty because the api request was get method and passing some data , then changed to post method and all working fine

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full component definition I can't 100% say for sure, but are you checking that the details is not empty before you log it out? When the component first mounts, it will be empty, until the request comes back -- when a second render will occur.

Typically, in the component render you would render nothing until it comes back. It's up to you to handle the case where the network request is still in flight:

```
render() {
   if (Object.keys(this.props.details).length === 0) return null

   // rest of component
}
```

It would probably be better to use `isFetching` in the condition but you will need another action just before the fetch call to set this.

Probably the reason the action doesn't even fire is your render already blew up because it couldn't handle the empty case.

Another problem could be if you have not configured https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk on your store. You are using thunks, so you might see what you're seeing if you didn't configure them.

Incidentally, you probably want the dispatch in `componentWillMount` and not `componentDidMount`. Did mount will unnecessarily wait for the first render pass before launching the request. It'll be fractionally quicker in will mount.

Comment: When I added the return code inside render also seems like same empty output  . also componentWillMount this one also same ,  also regarding redux thunk issue this app has other apis already working  this api is a new api im trying to access . so one for this the action is not runnig

Comment: const {details} = this.props;
 console.log('---', details) this is how i called inside component ,  am i missing something here  this shows the empty error

Answer (score 0):

i have figure out that your case syntax is wrong it should be like this inside reducer switch

case "FETCHSUCCESS":

second you have to warp your component with **connect** and then get the state from your reducer.

to view you result you need to directly interact with reducer for data rather than using data from component state.

and use show loader inside component until **API** calls end

Comment: sory for the type i ddint use real action names all dummy real actions dirent names just used to show the bug here